# Go validation using envoy proxy validator and gogo protobuf

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, proto

I am trying write plugin to generate validate go files. Which uses https://github.com/mwitkow/go-proto-validators and envoy proxy validator https://github.com/envoyproxy/protoc-gen-validate. Below is my command

```
protoc  \
--proto_path=${GOPATH}/src \
--proto_path=${GOPATH}/pkg/mod/github.com/gogo/protobuf@v1.3.2 \
--proto_path=${GOPATH}/pkg/mod/github.com/envoyproxy/protoc-gen-validate@v0.1.0
--proto_path=. \
--gogo_out=. \
—-validate_out=“lang=go:.\”
--govalidators_out=gogoimport=true:. \
proto/*.proto
```

when I run above command I am getting below error? any suggestion expert on how to resolve this. Appreciate your help.

```
zsh: command not found: --proto_path=.
zsh: command not found: --govalidators_out=gogoimport=true:.
```

After adding the missing "/"

```
protoc  \
--proto_path=${GOPATH}/src \
--proto_path=${GOPATH}/pkg/mod/github.com/gogo/protobuf@v1.3.2 \
--proto_path=${GOPATH}/pkg/mod/github.com/envoyproxy/protoc-gen-validate@v0.1.0 \
--proto_path=. \
--gogo_out=. \
-—go_out=":./generated" \
—-validate_out="lang=go:./generated" \
--govalidators_out=gogoimport=true:. \
proto/test.proto
```

I am getting **Unknown flag: -?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you missed `\` after get-validate and later...

```sh
protoc  \
--proto_path=${GOPATH}/src \
--proto_path=${GOPATH}/pkg/mod/github.com/gogo/protobuf@v1.3.2 \
--proto_path=${GOPATH}/pkg/mod/github.com/envoyproxy/protoc-gen-validate@v0.1.0 \
--proto_path=. \
--gogo_out=. \
—-validate_out="lang=go:." \
--govalidators_out=gogoimport=true:. \
proto/*.proto
```

Comment: thanks I modify my command accordingly. Now getting Unknown flag: -? any suggestion on this

Comment: I suggest you remove all flags (or half them) to locate one unknown to `protoc`. Quite possible that one of the plugins presented in command is missing (if not all).

Comment: I apologies I didn't understand I am new to Go. What flags you are referring here

Comment: each of the values you passing to `protoc`, in you r example all of them starts with `--`, `--proto_path` is (lets called it) "native" to protoc, while `validate_out`, `govalidators_out` and `gogo_out` are not. not native supplied by plugins (you posted two links. Some of it not found, I guess you forgot to install them (see instructions on each of the plugins github pages).